# disk space is full diffrent in centos 7 and fedora 31

Tags: centos

I created a test environment that has 2 VMs

1- Fedora 31 
2- CentOS 7

I create and copy many file to fill / on my VMs

Result :
1- in Fedora / is full and 100% without free space , and after restart fedora doesn't boot

2- In CentOS I  can fill all space on / , and stay 16K free and after reboot CentOS boots correctly

Does CentOS make reserve space for / and OS and Fedora does not?

Comment: Update your question with both vm's filesystem `df -PTH` and logs where your fedora stuck during reboot. So many reasons need more details.

Answer (score 0):

this is just like comparing submarine & space stations ....    both have their own concepts/decisions/maybe reservations as you mentioned etc... etc.... 
you test is just a waste of time In my opinion
Please read roles and comparaison again between REDHAT/CENTOS/FEDORA

make same reservation on each distrib & test each boot condition   is more revelent. But NEVER compare two different distos even in same family

Comment: thanks a lot , its ok , but i want view and chan space reserve for distribute and where i can change it ?

Comment: this depends on the file system you re using and can be set with tunefs command for example